# sql query assigning instructor to a different regno using two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Here is the code i have tried but it fails as i thought it would does anyone know how to get this to work please?.

```
UPDATE Instructor,Car
SET CarNo='3', regNO ='RF10 AAF'
WHERE CarNo='7',regNo='QW64 YTR';
```

Comment: Please try to work on your problem. There is no table structure, neither regno nor instructor is needed in the title, there is no formatting. And finally you should search for "update join".

Comment: if i update just one table its fine i.e UPDATE Instructor
SET CarNo='3'
WHERE CarNo='7';
but i want to update two tables at the same time instructor and car.

Comment: You can only update a single table in a single update query. If you want to update both the car and instructor tables you will need two UPDATE statements. However, it isn't clear what you are trying to do as it isn't clear which field belongs to which table.

Comment: Saying what works doesn't make your problem any clearer in this case. Oh, and I forgot, you didn't include the error message.

Comment: ok instructor table contains the carNo and the car table has regNo. so i want to update these values at the same time in one query so that the name of the driver is assigned to a new carno and a new regno that already exists in my database.

Comment: So do you just want to update the instructor that has car 7 to actually have car 3? Because if car 3 already has reg no 'RF10 AAF' then that appears to be all you need to do. Otherwise you'd need to update the instructor table and then update the car table in a separate UPDATE statement. You can put it in a transaction if you want the update to be atomic.

Comment: ok instructor table contains the  colmun carNo and the car table has column regNo. so i want to update the carno from 7 to 3 and the regno from one liscence to another at the same time in one query so that the name of the driver is assigned to a new carno and a new regno that already exists in my database.

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

UPDATE Instructor SET CarNo='3' WHERE CarNo='7';

UPDATE Car SET regNO ='RF10 AAF' WHERE regNo='QW64 YTR';

COMMIT;
```

You should make sure this is what you want to do though. Understand that if the instructor is being associated with car 3 that already has the reg No that you want, you don't need to update the Car table; the instructor should be associated with the new car's reg no when you update the instructor's car no (assuming that there is a relationship between the instructor and car tables based on carNo).

Comment: tried the above but i get this error message.  Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "UPDATE" LINE 3: UPDATE Instructor SET CarNo='3' WHERE CarNo='7' ^.

Comment: Might need a semi-colon after BEGIN TRANSACTION. I'm not too sure, I've written T-SQL rather than Postgres. Shouldn't be too far different :-/

Comment: the first part of the staement worked however i realised that although ican rename him to the carno 3 what i think i need to do is switch his carno and reg for that of the other driver is that a way of doing this do you know please? so instead of updating i need to switch places with a another driver. who has the car he now needs to have if that makes sense sry if im not totaly clear on this.

Comment: Easiest way to do that is to just have two more update statements which do the inverse operation, e.g. UPDATE Instructor SET CarNo = '7' WHERE CarNo = '3'; and another for the car reg no.

Comment: i need to do this in one statement

Comment: i managed to solve simply by putting UPDATE Instructor
SET CarNo='3'
WHERE CarNo='7';    As the car no is the foreiegn key of primary key so by swapping the carno it actually results in automatically assigning the driver to the new registration. Thanks for all your help guys .